# Marshalling Local Date within Observable List

Tags: java, javafx, jaxb, marshalling, fxml

I have an Observable List of class Bills. This list is marshalled using the following

```
    public void saveBillsToFile(File file){
    try{    
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext
                .newInstance(BillListWrapper.class);
        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        BillListWrapper wrapper = new BillListWrapper();
        wrapper.setBills(budget.getBills());

        m.marshal(wrapper, file);

        //TODO setPersonFilePath(file);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
```

I however get a NoSuchMethodException when I add an LocalDate object property to the bill class. I found an post that said I need to create an XML adapter like

```
public class LocalDateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, LocalDate> {
public LocalDate unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
    return LocalDate.parse(v);
}

public String marshal(LocalDate v) throws Exception {
    return v.toString();
}
}
```

I am unsure of where to put this however. I'm assuming it would have something to do with my wrapper

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "bills")
public class BillListWrapper {

private List<Bill> bills;

@XmlElement(name = "bill")
public List<Bill> getBills() {
    return bills;
}

public void setBills(List<Bill> bills) {
    this.bills = bills;
}
```

The Bills class:

```
public class Bill{

//Properties
private StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
private StringProperty description = new SimpleStringProperty();
private IntegerProperty amount = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
private IntegerProperty payable = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
private IntegerProperty allocatedAmount = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
private IntegerProperty owedAmount = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
private IntegerProperty priority = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
private IntegerProperty recurrence = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
private StringProperty payments = new SimpleStringProperty();
//private ObjectProperty<LocalDate> lastPayment = new SimpleObjectProperty<LocalDate>();
int originalAmount;
int originalOwed;


public Bill(){
    name.set("");
    amount.set(0);
    owedAmount.set(0);
    allocatedAmount.set(0);
    description.set("");
    payments.set("");
    originalAmount = 0;
}

public void allocate(int allocation){
    System.out.println(allocation);
    allocatedAmount.set(originalAmount + allocation);
    if(allocation > amount.get()){
        owedAmount.set(originalOwed - allocation + amount.get());
    }else if(allocation < amount.get()){
        owedAmount.set(originalOwed - allocation + amount.get());
    }else if(allocation == amount.get()){
        owedAmount.set(originalOwed);
    }

}

public void pay(){
    if(payable.get() <= allocatedAmount.get()){
        allocatedAmount.set(allocatedAmount.get() - payable.get());
    }else{
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setTitle("Error!");
        alert.setHeaderText("Can't Pay");
        alert.setContentText("There is not enough money allocated to pay this.\nChange the value and try again.");

        alert.showAndWait();
    }
}
 //Getters and setters removed
```

The stack trace:

> (java:15134): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita", Jul 19, 2017 4:12:01 PM
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ClassFactory create0 INFO: No default
>   constructor found on class java.time.LocalDate
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.time.LocalDate.()     at
>   java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)  at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ClassFactory.create0(ClassFactory.java:89)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.createInstance(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:270)     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.createInstance(UnmarshallingContext.java:684)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StructureLoader.startElement(StructureLoader.java:171)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:559)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:538)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:153)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:351)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2784)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:243)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
>     at
>   javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
>     at
>   javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:162)
>     at
>   javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:171)
>     at
>   javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:189)
>     at budget.Main.loadBillsFromFile(Main.java:62)  at
>   budget.Main.start(Main.java:39)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$106(LauncherImpl.java:863)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$119(PlatformImpl.java:326)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$117(PlatformImpl.java:295)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$118(PlatformImpl.java:294)
>     at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
>     at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)  at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$450(GtkApplication.java:139)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> Exception in Application start method
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start
>   method    at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$99(LauncherImpl.java:182)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.time.LocalDate.()     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ClassFactory.create0(ClassFactory.java:96)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.createInstance(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:270)     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.createInstance(UnmarshallingContext.java:684)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StructureLoader.startElement(StructureLoader.java:171)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:559)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:538)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:153)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:351)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2784)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:243)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
>     at
>   javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
>     at
>   javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:162)
>     at
>   javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:171)
>     at
>   javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:189)
>     at budget.Main.loadBillsFromFile(Main.java:62)  at
>   budget.Main.start(Main.java:39)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$106(LauncherImpl.java:863)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$119(PlatformImpl.java:326)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$117(PlatformImpl.java:295)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$118(PlatformImpl.java:294)
>     at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
>     at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)  at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$450(GtkApplication.java:139)
>     ... 1 more Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   java.time.LocalDate.()  at
>   java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)  at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ClassFactory.create0(ClassFactory.java:89)
>     ... 35 more Exception running application budget.Main

Comment: How does your `Bill` class look like?

Comment: I updated the post to include the class

Comment: When asking about an exception, always post the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Added the stack trace

Comment: Have you tried to add [`XmlJavaTypeAdapter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlJavaTypeAdapter.html) to your wrapper class?

Comment: You probably have to write more type adapters for javafx properties.

Comment: Can you elaborate or give an example. I don't really understand